# 静的データメンバ定義中のラムダ式がクラススコープになる理由

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11で静的データメンバ定義(`X::singleton`)のラムダ式中から、該当クラス(`X`)のprivateメソッド(`X::X()`と`X::init()`)にアクセスできるのはどうしてですか？ C++仕様での該当パラグラフを知りたいです。

```
class X {
  X() {}
  void init() {}
public:
  X(const X&) = default;
  void mf() const {}
  static const X& singleton;
};

const X& X::singleton = []{
  static X obj;  // X::X()にアクセス可能
  obj.init();    // X::init()にアクセス可能
  return obj;
}();

int main()
{
//  X x;       // X::X()アクセス不可
//  x.init();  // X::init()アクセス不可
  X::singleton.mf();
}
```

LiveDemo: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hqOvjVHyBdfV5HtE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237729/c11-lambdas-can-access-my-private-members-why

こちらに同様の質問があります。101010氏の文を引用させていただきます。

> § 9.4.2/2 Static data members [class.static.data]:
>
> The initializer expression in the deﬁnition of a static data member is in the scope of its class.
>
> § 5.1.2/2&3 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]:
>
> 2 The evaluation of a lambda-expression results in a prvalue temporary (12.2). This temporary is called the closure object. A lambda-expression shall not appear in an unevaluated operand (Clause 5). [ Note: A closure object behaves like a function object (20.9).-end note]
>
> 3 The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type - called the closure type - whose properties are described below. This class type is not an aggregate (8.5.1). The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

補足をしますが、まずstaticデータメンバの初期化式のスコープがクラスのものになるという点ですが、これはC++03から存在する文面です。

デモのコードは、実際には以下の様なコードと同義になります。
ただし、以下は擬似コードであり、実際に生成されるコードは処理系に依存します。

```
class X {
    X() {}
    void init() {}
public:
    X(const X&) = default;
    void mf() const {}
    static const X& singleton;

private:
    struct Lambda
    {
        const X& operator()(){
            static X obj;  // X::X()にアクセス可能
            obj.init();    // X::init()にアクセス可能
            return obj;
        }
    };
};

const X& X::singleton = Lambda{}();

int main()
{
//  X x;       // X::X()アクセス不可
//  x.init();  // X::init()アクセス不可
    X::singleton.mf();
}
```

default指定を使用せず、Lambda{}()をLambda()()に書き換えれば、C++03でも動作します。